# An acid and Sodium carbonate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

I have to explain why it 'fuzzes' when an acid is added to Sodium carbonate? And what are the relevant Chemical equation(s).. 
I'm stuck with this question. I'd appreciate some help here.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acids in the presence of carbonates produce carbonic acid which then decomposes into carbon dioxide gas (the fizz) and water. Sodium is a 'spectator ion'; i.e., does not react. Reaction equation is a metathesis double replacement:

$$\ce{HA + 2Na^+ + CO3^2- <=> A^- + 2Na^+ + HCO3^-}$$

$$\ce{HA + HCO3^- <=> A^- + H2CO3}$$

$$\ce{H2CO3 <=>  H2O + CO2(g)}$$